# How to match all the non numeric characters except a plus symbol using regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

How can i match any characters that are not 0-9 and + using regular expression? I want to be able to match all the characters except numbers and plus sign.

/\D+/ matches all the char that are not numbers but i want it to be false for numbers and +

Comment: try `/[^0-9+]+/`

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `[^0-9+]+` pattern, as per [regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/rzbZX8/1):

```
[^0-9+]+

Match a single character not present in the list below [^0-9+]+

+ Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
0-9 a single character in the range between 0 (index 48) and 9 (index 57) (case sensitive)
+ matches the character + literally (case sensitive)
```

Answer (score -4):

You can use this expression: [^0-9.$]

Comment: This won't do what OP asks for. Instead it matches neither `0-9` nor `.` nor `$` literally. Additionally, there's no quantifier, so it matches only one character.